# In which correctly way should be the equation I come up with his in my mind.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have a equation $x^2 = 2y^2+3z^2$.

And if I want to make it equal to 0 which one is the corretly way of doing it.

$0 = -x^2+2y^2+3z^2$

or

$x^2-2y^2-3z^2 = 0 $

I came up with this in my mind and I am confused. Is this posible?

Comment: Both are correct. However, note that the second one should read $x^2-2y^2-3z^2=0.$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). You may want to [edit] your question to improve its appearance, and maybe fix uncapitalized I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct, the 2nd one is transformed into the first by multiplication of -1. And I believe that you mean $-3z^2$.